# Why can't I use a select elements with object based options within reactive forms? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form that includes a parent form (country) and a child form array (statesForm) with a select element that has object based options. I am using [ngValue] to set the value of the select element to the object. When using the "(change)" event of the select list, I am unable to retrieve the selected value from the form control.

I have whittled this example down from a much more complicated page. So, I understand that there may be other ways to accomplish, but I am interested in figuring out specifically, why I can't get object based select options to work with this setup.

Here is link to the stackblitz demonstrating the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jigxyl

Here are the relevant parts of the stackblitz code

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCountry().subscribe(
            country => {
                this.country = country;
                this.countryForm = this.buildFormGroup();
            },
            (error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }

    CityCompare(c1: City, c2: City): boolean {
        return c1 && c2 ? c1.name === c2.name : c1 === c2;
    }

    onSelectedStateChange(index: any): void {
        var rowsFormArray = <FormArray>this.countryForm.controls["statesForm"];
        var formGroup = <FormGroup>rowsFormArray.controls[index];

        this.selectedCity = formGroup.controls["selectedCity"].value;
        console.log(this.selectedCity);
    }

    private buildFormGroup(): FormGroup {
        var formArray = new FormArray([]);

        for (let i = 0; i < this.country.states.length; i++) {
            var state = this.country.states[i];

            var formGroup = new FormGroup({});

            var formControl = new FormControl(state.selectedCity, [Validators.required]);
            formGroup.addControl("selectedCity", formControl);

            formArray.push(formGroup);
        }

        return new FormGroup({
            statesForm: formArray
        });
    }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="countryForm">
    <div>
      <p>
      I am using reactive forms and trying to use objects to set the options list
      of a select element
      <br/>
      This form containts a form array as well. 
      <br/>
      No matter which option I choose, the form control always evaluates to the first options<br/>
      --------------------------------------
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        Country:{{country?.name}}
    </div>
    <div formArrayName="statesForm">
        <div *ngFor="let state of country?.states; let $index = index">
            <div>State: {{state.abbreviation}}</div>
            <div [formGroupName]="$index">
                <select
                    class="form-control input-sm"
                    formControlName="selectedCity"
                    [compareWith]="CityCompare"
                    (change)="onSelectedStateChange($index)"
                >
                    <option *ngFor="let city of state?.cities" [ngValue]="state?.selectedCity">
                        {{ city?.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    Chosen object:{{this.selectedCity | json}}
</form>
```

Comment: You need to put your actual code in the question in addition to your stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to set the ngValue to the city object , the selected value alreay set you can check the for

```
   <div formArrayName="statesForm">
        <div *ngFor="let state of country?.states; let $index = index">
            <div>State: {{state.abbreviation}}</div>
            <div [formGroupName]="$index">
                <select
                    class="form-control input-sm"
                    formControlName="selectedCity"
                    [compareWith]="CityCompare"
                    (change)="onSelectedStateChange($index)">
                    <option *ngFor="let city of state?.cities" [ngValue]="city">
                        {{ city?.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czcfzp)

> you don't need to track the selected value the form already will sync
>   with the ui so any change will reflect to the formGroup

```
getSelectedStateValue(index) {
  return (this.countryForm.get('statesForm') as FormArray).controls[index].value
}
```

*template*

```
Chosen object:{{getSelectedStateValue($index) | json}}
```

Comment: great! thank you! I could not see the issue. Thanks for pointing this out and being a second pair of eyes!!

Answer (score 1):

the `(change)` event is a template driven forms method, you want to subscribe to valueChanges on the form control when using reative forms:

```
 this.countryForm.get('statesForm').valueChanges.subscribe(v => 
              this.onSelectedStateChange(v[0]));
```

blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxxuxy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

this case is a little weird bc you have a group with an array with controls, but only one selected city, when it seems like there could be multiple.

you've also for some reason set the value of each option to the state's selected city, you need to set the option value to each city:

```
[ngValue]="city"
```

Comment: in case there is multiple states like have more than one country the valueChanges will emit every time an array will be a hard to determine the selected value unless he do some change to compare the old selected value with the new one, 

Comment: @malbarmawi would be, but it'd also be a very strange use case if his goal was to find the most recently selected city in a list of select forms.